# Better way to access individual elements in a tensor

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am trying to access the elements of a tensor `a`, with the indexes defined in tensor `b`.

```
a=tf.constant([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])
b=tf.constant([0,1,1,0])
```

I want the output to be

```
out = [1 6 7 4]
```

What I have tried:

```
out=[]
for i in range(a.shape[1]):
    out.append(a[b[i],i])

out=tf.stack(out) #[1 6 7 4]
```

This is giving the correct output, but I'm looking for a better and a compact way to do it.

Also my logic doesnt work when the shape of `a` is something like `(2,None)` since I cannot iterate with `range(a.shape[1])`, it would help me if the answer included this case too

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tf.one_hot()` and `tf.boolean_mask()`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

a_tf = tf.placeholder(shape=(2,None),dtype=tf.int32)
b_tf = tf.placeholder(shape=(None,),dtype=tf.int32)

index = tf.one_hot(b_tf,a_tf.shape[0])
out = tf.boolean_mask(tf.transpose(a_tf),index)

a=np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])
b=np.array([0,1,1,0])
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(out,feed_dict={a_tf:a,b_tf:b}))

# print
[1 6 7 4]
```