# How to efficiently get values of each row in a tensor using indices?

Tags: python, tensorflow, slice, z-index, tensor

I have a tensor called my_tensor with tha shape of `[batch_size, seq_length]` and I have another tensor named idx with tha shape of `[batch_size, 1]` which is comprised of indices which start at 0 and finish at "seq_length".

I want to extract the values of in each row of my_tensor on using the indices defined in idx.

I tried to use `tf.gather_nd` and `tf.gather` but I was not successful.

Consider the following example:

```
batch_size = 3
seq_length = 5
idx = [2, 0, 4]

my_tensor = tf.random.uniform(shape=(batch_size, seq_length))
```

I want to get the values at

```
[[0, 2],
 [1, 0],
 [3, 4]]
```

from my_tensor.

I have to do further process over them, so I would like to have them at the same time (I don't know if it is even possible) and in an efficient way; however, I could not come up with any other methods.

I appreciate any help :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [slicing a tensor along a dimension with given index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55280388/slicing-a-tensor-along-a-dimension-with-given-index).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to first convert your set of indices into a boolean mask which you can then use to reduce `my_tensor` as you have described using the [boolean_mask](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/boolean_mask?hl=en) operation.

You can accomplish this by [one-hot encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot) the `idx` tensor.

So, where `idx = [2, 0, 4]` we can do `tf.one_hot(idx, seq_length)` in order to convert it to something like this:

```py
[ [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
  [1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
  [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.] ]
```

Then, putting it all together for, say `my_tensor`:

```py
[ [0.6413697 , 0.4079175 , 0.42499018, 0.3037368 , 0.8580252 ],
  [0.8698617 , 0.29096508, 0.11531639, 0.25421357, 0.5844104 ],
  [0.6442119 , 0.31816053, 0.6245482 , 0.7249261 , 0.7595779 ] ]
```

we can proceed as follows:

```py
result = tf.boolean_mask(my_tensor, tf.one_hot(idx,seq_length))
```

to give:

```py
[0.42499018, 0.8698617 , 0.7595779 ]
```

as expected